# Reducing 1 band raster size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, file-size

I have a 1 band 32 bit signed file system raster, with 4 attributes in addition to the value and count attributes with about 47000 rows, that is 55gb.

I wanted to reduce the size of this raster without losing spatial information and attribute information.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the exact image dimensions, the compression algorithm, and the dynamic range of your data (min, max, mean).